# Proper way to loop for a promise response

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loops, cordova, promise

I have a primary and secondary sms service for my app.  If the primary fails, for any issue, I want to default to the secondary service.

Here is the flow:

> 1. send to sms service
> 2. sms service responds with receipt acknowledgement
> 3. sms service sends message to phone carrier
> 4. sms service receives phone carrier receipt
> 5. my app can then query sms service for carrier receipt

However, due to the time frames involved (internet, carrier delays, etc), I need to loop #5 until the carrier receipt comes in...or times out...to determine if it needs to go to the secondary service.  Currently I am doing a 3 second timeout delay before querying for #5 - but I would like to convert that to a 1 second loop to ensure that if #4 takes longer than 3 seconds that my #5 will still working correctly.

```
  $scope.sendCode = function() {
    $scope.errColor = "red" ;
    $scope.errMsg = "SENDING AUTH CODE" ;
    var newCode = getRandom(10000,99999) ;
    //var tktCode = new Date().format("yyyymmdd")+ "_" +getRandom(10000,999999) ;
    var smsNumber = getDB("user_phone") ;
    setDB("app_regCode",newCode) ;
    var msg = "App registration code: "+newCode+ ". Enter this code into the 'VERIFY CODE' input field" ;
    var tReq = twilio(smsNumber,msg) ;

    var smsCarrier = getDB("dev_carrier") ;
    if (!smsCarrier) {
      smsCarrier = "No Carrier Info" ;
    }
    var smsEmail = $scope.userObj.user_email ;
    if (!smsEmail) {
      smsEmail = "No Email" ;
    }

    $scope.errColor ;
    $scope.errMsg ;
    var error = {} ;  
    var smsShortCode = vendorData.twilioShortCode ;
    var smsLongCode = vendorData.twilioLongCode ;  
    // log message sent to internal API
    $scope.smsID = logSMS(smsNumber,smsLongCode,smsShortCode,msg,smsCarrier,smsEmail,"Twilio") ;
    $http(tReq).then(function(response) {
      $scope.errColor = "green" ;
      $scope.errMsg = "SENT!  Confirming Delivery" ;
      smsResponse = response.data ;
      if (smsResponse.sid) {
        //update smsSent record
        apiService.all("PUT",[{table:"smsSent",sid:"rid",sidValue:$scope.smsID,soloField:1,dataInfo:{smsTkt:smsResponse.sid}}]) ;
      }
      if (smsResponse.status.match(/(queued|accepted|sending|sent)/i)) {  //if (sms.success == true) {

        // need to replace this with a proper 1 second loop
        // to test for "delivered" carrier receipt
        // if status still (queued|accepted|sending|sent), then loop until its updated
        // final receipt statuses are: Delivered, Undelivered, Failed

        setTimeout(function() {  
          return $http(twilioVerify(smsResponse.uri))
          .then(function(response) {
            // now check status of message to determine if needed to exit or go to back up service
            //return $http(twilioVerify(smsResponse.uri))
            if (response.data.status == "delivered") {
              $scope.errColor = "green"
              $scope.errMsg = "Delivery Confirmed" ;
              messageSent('Primary');
            } else {
              //backup service
              // determine fail reason, send to secondary if necessary
              messageFail('Primary') ;
              $scope.errColor = "red"
              $scope.errMsg = "Problem detected, trying secondary service" ;              
              secondSMS(smsNumber,msg) ;
            }
          }) ;
        },3000) ;

      } else {  // failed response from Twilio, send to MissionMobile
        $scope.errColor = "red" ;
        $scope.errMsg = "Problem detected, attempting secondary service"
        messageFail('Primary') ;
        secondarySMS(smsNumber,msg) ;
      }
    }, function(thisError) {  // failed communication to Twilio, send to MissionMobile
        $scope.errColor = "red" ;
        $scope.errMsg = "Issue sending code, attempting secondary service" ;
        messageFail('Primary') ;
        secondarySMS(smsNumber,msg) ;
    }).catch(function(error) {
        $scope.errColor = error.errColor ;
        $scope.errMsg = error.errMsg ;
    }) ;
  }
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the issue, just found error in your code. If you have setTimeout, return inside will not work. You need to create explicit Promise using library $q in AngularJS or native Promise, return that promise outside of setTimeout and resolve/reject it inside.

Comment: On side note, do not use `setTimeout` rather prefer `$timeout` as it comes under angular digest cycle. Core JS functions are not a good thing to use with `angularjs`

Comment: @ShashankVivek - true.  I was using $timeout and switched to setTimeout for a testing purpose.  But ultimately I need to get rid of a timeout and replace with a loop of some sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `$interval` :

```
    final_check_interval = $interval(function() {  
      return $http(twilioVerify(smsResponse.uri))
      .then(function(response) {
        // now check status of message to determine if needed to exit or go to back up service
        //return $http(twilioVerify(smsResponse.uri))
        if (response.data.status == "delivered") {
          $scope.errColor = "green"
          $scope.errMsg = "Delivery Confirmed" ;
          messageSent('Primary');
        } else {
          //backup service
          // determine fail reason, send to secondary if necessary
          messageFail('Primary') ;
          $scope.errColor = "red"
          $scope.errMsg = "Problem detected, trying secondary service" ;              
          secondSMS(smsNumber,msg) ;
        }
      }) ;
    },1000) ;
```

and on `messageSent()`, make sure you cancel the time which will be triggered every 1 secs:

```
$interval.cancel(final_check_interval);
```

I hope you got the clue of what you are looking for

Comment: Worked like a charm...thanks!  I added a loop counter of 5...`else if (response.data.status.match (/(undelivered|failed)/i) || counter = 5)) {   //cancel }` to timeout after 5 seconds and auto default to secondary service.

Comment: @rolinger Awesome !